# Tables and record were lost when I restart docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Every time I `docker-compose down` or restart docker, my tables disappear **even though I've always volume** it!

```
version: "3.3"
services:
   mysql_db:
      image: "mysql:8.0"
      hostname: mysql_db
      container_name: mysql_db
      restart: always
      ports:
         - 3306:3306
      environment:
         TZ: Asia/Bangkok
         MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 0000
         MYSQL_DATABASE: aquaros
         MYSQL_USER: arima
         MYSQL_PASSWORD: 0000
      volumes:
         - "/home/khynpleum/mysql_data/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
         - "/home/khunpleum/mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
```

I use

- Windows10
- Ubuntu(WSL2)
- Docker on Ubuntu (Docker Desktop)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue earlier. To solve this I used the ubuntu container. Inside the ubuntu container install MySQL-server and store the data. Now commit the ubuntu container. Tables won't disappear this way.

Comment: So if I commit this mysql container after I've done, **Are my tables still there?**

Comment: If a custom MySQL image solves the problem, please edit this answer and add the Dockerfile you used.  I'd generally advise avoiding `docker commit`, since "I installed some stuff on top of an Ubuntu image" isn't really something you can repeat (...when there's a critical security advisory in MySQL in 6 months and you _must_ rebuild the image).